# Place data template and styles to generated buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, controls, datatemplate

## What I'll to do

I'll add some `SubMenuButton`s *(code below)* on an `ItemControl` generated by code behind in the view model of the page where the `ItemControl` is placed on. I've tried 2 solutions and give me 2 different results.

---

## 1<sup>st</sup> solution I've tried

### Code

Here is the class I've made:

```
public class SubMenuButton : Button
{
    public Page TargetPage { get; set; }
    public FontAwesomeIcon Icon { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public SubMenuButton()
    {
        Style = App.Current.FindResource("submenuButtonStyle") as Style; 
        // comment line above for 2nd solution I've tried
    }

    public SubMenuButton(string text, Page targetPage, ICommand command, 
                                                            FontAwesomeIcon icon) : this()
    {
        Icon = icon;
        Text = text;
        TargetPage = targetPage;
        CommandParameter = targetPage;
        Command = command;
    }
}
```

For this class I've also made a `Style` for display the icon and the text and ser also some properties to make it better.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
                    xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
                    xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/"
                    xmlns:uie="clr-namespace:Provar2.Client.DesktopApp.UIElements">

    <Style x:Key="transparantButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="auto"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="submenuButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource transparantButtonStyle}" 
           TargetType="{x:Type uie:SubMenuButton}">

        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding TargetPage}" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type uie:SubMenuButton}">
                    <Canvas Height="auto">
                        <fa:FontAwesome Icon="{Binding Icon}" Width="30" Height="30"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

This is where the `SubMenuButton` must be generated

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Gray" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding SubMenuItems}" />
```

### Result

But for this solution I've got this exception:

> **`BindingExpression`:** `Text` property not found on object `SubMenuPageViewModel`.
>
> ```
> BindingExpression:
> Path=Text; 
> DataItem='SubMenuPageViewModel' (HashCode=28642977);
> ```
>
> Target element is `TextBlock` target property is `Text` *(type `String`)*

---

## 2<sup>nd</sup> solution I've tried

### Code

I've also tried to add a property `ItemTemplate` to my `ItemsControl`.

```
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource submenuButtonTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" 
              Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Background="Green" ItemsSource="{Binding SubMenuItems}" />
```

I've also comment some lines to my code inside empty constructor from `SubMenuButton`.

and add this data template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="submenuButtonTemplate" DataType="{x:Type scr:SubMenuButton}">
    <Canvas Height="auto">
        <fa:FontAwesome Icon="{Binding Icon}" Width="30" Height="30"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </Canvas>
</DataTemplate>
```

### Result

Now I don't have the exception but I've got this:

[image: UI]

The green rectangle is my `ItemTemplate`, the 2 `SubMenuButton`s *(because I generate 2 `SubMenuButton`s)* I've circled with a yellow pen.

---

## Question

Could you fix my problem?

Comment: Do you have a property named `Text` inside your `SubMenuPageViewModel`?

Comment: @Ruben: No, I don't need that inside my view model also the property `Icon` gives an exception. **PS** I go update my question with an other thing I've tried.

Comment: If you´re going for the `Text`-Property inside your `SubMenuButton` you should use `DependencyProperty` instead of a normal `Property`

Comment: @Ruben: What is a `DependencyProperty`? I'm a young studying boy that don't understand it.

Comment: It gives you the ability to bind your properties inside XAML. Take a look at my example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextBlock tries to get Text property from DataContext, which doesn't have it. Add RelativeSource parameter to point that Text belong to `uie:SubMenuButton`

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=uie:SubMenuButton}}"/>
```

and if Text is implemented as `DependencyProperty` it will notify about changes, support binding, etc